# plot mysql data into chart

Tags: php, mysql, charts

I'm trying to use this chart generator from http://htmldrive.net/items/show/792/Rare-Accessible-charts-using-jQuery-and-HTML5.html

Here's the code which loads data from mysql database:
The query works, but I guess my interpretation of the example provided in the site was wrong. 
I get an output if I do it this way(predefined data):

```
<tr>
            <th scope="row">Profit</th>
              <td>5</td>
          <td>5</td>
   </tr>
```

But when I do it this way I get a blank output:

```
?>



<table>
    <caption> Reports</caption>
    <thead>

        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ ?>

        <th scope="col"><?php echo $row['Cust_Name']; ?></th>

        <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Subtotal</th>
              <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ ?>

        <td><?php echo $row['TOTAL_PUR']; ?></td>

        <?php } ?>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Profit</th>
                <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ ?>

        <td><?php echo $row['TOTALPROFIT']; ?></td>

        <?php } ?>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's what I'm getting:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first iteration through the rows, when you display the customer names, the fetch data pointer is at the end of the dataset... you're trying to fetch the set again without resetting the pointer.

Try issuing

```
mysql_data_seek($query, 0);
```

before the while loops to display total and profit